# How to include a dll used by the bridge component for an Edge extension with NativeMessaging?

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge-extension

I was able to attach a debugger to the process of the Win32 bridge component used by my AppService. This way I sawy that I'm getting module (dll) not found errors.
The dll is included in the Win32 directory of the UWP application (next to Win32 .exe).

Comment: Could please check barry's reply on [this similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd02199f-2a84-466b-baee-2e3104a2d197/desktop-bridge-dll-not-found-exception-in-uwp-application?forum=wpdevelop) firstly to see if help?

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio you should be able to create Appx Packages. The package ending with .appxupload has to be submitted to Store. At the same time Visual studio will create a package ending with .appxbundle which can use for internal testing.